# Q:How to test ActionMailer deliver_later with Turnip,capybara and Gherkin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara-webkit, rails-activejob, turnip

```
def deliver_mail
  ServiceMailer.activation().deliver_later
end
```

deliver_mail method is called from some controller.

I want to test like below - feature test using cucumber and capybara.

step 'push next button' do
  find("input.submit").click
end

```
Feature: Sending a mail to user
  Scenario: mail to a user
    When I push next button
    Then mail should be sent to a user
```

actually, when 'push next button' is pushed, mail is sent by deliver_mail method.

when I use deliver_now instead of deliver_later, I can test the code above.

but after I change deliver_now to deliver_later, I can not test.

so I referenced below.

http://chriswarren.github.io/rpsec/testing/2015/03/13/testing-emails-and-active-job-in-rspec-feature-tests.html

I tried to include 'ActiveJob::TestHelper' like 'include ActiveJob::TestHelper' in spec file.

and i modified step file like this.

```
step 'push next button' do
 　perform_enqueued_jobs do
    find("input.submit").click
 　end
end
```

but still doesn't work.

any hint and advice please.

Comment: So how do you test that mail has been sent? Show us code from your test with `expect` statement.

Comment: I added expect statement which use Turnip.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Delayed::Job for sending emails in a background, so when I test sending emails, I have two separate kinds of tests:

1) `rspec` - to check email body (in general, the method inside mailer) and sending the email itself

2) `cucumber` - to check if the email job was queued

In cucumber, I have the following code:

```
Then(/^A welcome email will be sent$/) do
  expect(Delayed::Job.count).to eq(1)
end
```

I think there is no need to check anything else from the cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not delaying jobs in test, and then checking the results of whatever DJ was supposed to run.

```
# rails_helper.rb

Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```